# Unexpected prompt behavior with JS

Tags: javascript, prompt

Trying to create a black jack simulator via Javascript as an exercise to increase my JS accumen (started coding a few weeks ago).

To try and make it simple and self contained (within JS, no html) I've tried to use a prompt to simulate action and response.

```
function action(){
    var response = prompt("What would you like to do \nInput 1 for Draw Card \nInput 2 for Play hand");
    if(response !== 1 || response !== 2){
        action();
    }
}
```

So, my question is, why does this continue to repeat itself when I enter 1 or 2. I would assume nothing should happen if either 1 or 2 are entered. I thought maybe this is because the prompt is saving the variable as a string, and so I changed the 1 and 2 to "1" and "2", but this did not fix the problem. I'm sure I'm missing something very simple. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. `"1"` matches because it's different than `"2"`, `"2"` matches because it's different than `"1"` and others match because they are different than `"1"` and `"2"`.

Instead, you should use the AND operator:

```
response !== "1" && response !== "2"
```

Comment: That makes sense. This fixed it, I'll mark answered in the morning. I'm going to bed! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Result of the `prompt` function is always a String, and [strict comparison `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) of the String and Number types will of course yield false:

```
"1" === 1 // false
```

Comment: Like I said in my question above, I tried using the following:
   if(response !== "1" || response !== "2"){

Comment: @JosephErickson `!==` is a strict equality, and `!=` is a loose equality operators. You are just negating them, but they are still strict, so: `response !== "1"` is the same as `!(response === "1")`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the type of comparison, the problem is his logic.

Comment: @Barmar Of course it has. It's the half of the problem. The second part is the logic, agree. But without correct comparison it will not work too.